# Showing that it is impossible to prove a statement from some facts.

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-fields

I am loving the question that is

> Show that the Completeness Axiom can not be proved using the 10 axioms of an ordered field.

The 10 axioms are 5 axioms for ordering properties and, commutativity, associativity, identities, inverses and ditiributivity.

I can not figure out the necessary condition to show something can not be proved by specified facts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that you can find an example of an ordered field which does not satisfy the completness axiom.

Now: $\Bbb Q$ is such a field.

If completeness were a logical consequence of the axioms, it would follow that every ordered field is complete. But $\Bbb Q$ isn't, so completenss is not a logical consequence of the axioms of ordered fields.

Comment: But what does it take to prove that $\mathbb Q$ does not satisfy the Completeness axiom ?

Comment: Proving that $\Bbb Q$ is not complete is the same thing as proving that at least one irrational number exists. This takes a bit of work, but it's quite standard. For example you can show that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Comment: I meant, what extra axiomatic is needed ?